# orphanRemoval not working properly in hibernate : Element inserted and removed from list is persisted in DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

We have an issue that sound like a bug in Hibernate dealing with **orphanRemoval**=**true** for a **oneToMany** **List** (with index).

Here is the simplified mapping :

```
public class ParentClass {

  [...]

  @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @OrderColumn(name = "pos", nullable = false)
  public List<ChildClass> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

}
```

And the child class :

```
public class ChildClass {
    [...]

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "parent_id")
    public ParentClass getParent() {
        return parent;
    } 
}
```

Given this mapping, the following scenario is failing :

1. Fetch a *Parent* from DB
2. Add a child to it
3. Get something else from DB (not same entity), producing a partial flush
4. Remove the child from the parent
5. Leave the transaction

Here is the code

```
@Transactional
public void test() {

  // 1)
  ParentClass parent = entityManager.find(ParentClass.class, "some-id");

  // 2)
  ChildClass child = new ChildClass(parent);
  parent.getChildren().add(child);

  // 3)
  entityManager.find(SomethingElse.class, "2");

  // 4)
  parent.getChildren().remove(child);  
}
```

In that case, the child allocation is inserted into DB and not removed at te end of the transaction.

However, if we don't do step 3), the child allocation is correctly not persisted in DB

Is that a bug ? A wrong mapping ?
Is there a workaround for it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is a bug. I bet you don't use the last version of Hibernate (4.3.8), and that it is related (if not the same issue) to this issue: [[HHH-9330] orphanRemoval=true does not work in bidirectional relationships (without cascading)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1182303) Even if you use the last version, this bug could still exist. If so, please report it and then report the URL to the bug here somewhere. Workaround: try adding the child only when sure it must be persisted or also try setting to null the parent in the child:

`child.setParent(null);`

Also as another workaround you may try using Hibernate sessions, instead of EntityManager (as it is written in Hibernate's forum).

Comment: Thanks, 
I just tried it, by setting parent to null at 4) 

But instead of a DELETE, in produces an UPDATE, with parentId to null, which is forbidden by the DB (we have explicit not null constraint).

Comment: And BTW, we use Hibernate 4.2.2

Comment: I see, why not call `em.remove(child);` instead (as workadound, of course)?

Comment: Yes that's what we will finally do.
It's just that currently we were relying on the assertion that Hiberante would nicely perist the state of our model without the need to call explicitely em.remove() each time we remove something.

This also bring some inconsistency in the design : We would rather not use any persistance related service in the low level business services.

Comment: I am afraid as long as you do not update to the last version (note that also version 4.3.7 seems to be affected, as this bug correction is pretty recent) you will have to do such tricks (you should at least add a comment to your code with the link to the bug). What I mean, you better leave this code as it is, without the risk of introducing new bugs/undesired behaviour, as it works at least right now.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention: you could try adding the `CascadeType.REMOVE` as a workaround to your problem.

Comment: Just adding a scenario that I faced earlier. Casedetype/orphanremoval (with latest version of hibernate) did not work with JPQL (i.e. em.executeUpdate() with "DELETE FROM .." query) unless I explicitly fetch the entity and invoked remove() via entitymanager.

Comment: According to this issue it seems the bug is still pressent: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9571

Comment: Still a bug in 2023? Dude..

Answer (score 3):

You need to set both sides of the association when removing a Child:

```
child.setParent(null);
parent.getChildren().remove(child);
```

The orphan-removal is not sufficient in your case. If the one-to-many side was a unidirectional association, then you could simply remove the Child from the List and the delete would propagate to the Child entity.

When you have a bi-directional association, you need to have both sides in sync. That's why you need to de-associate the Child from the Parent entity upon deletion.

Comment: I am afraid the orpahnRemoval feature in a bidirectional relationship should also work. The link I have posted in my answer is where the stuff is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JPA annotation `@PreRemove` which might be helpful in your particular situation.  Try adding this to the child entity so it can remove itself from the parent:

```
@PreRemove
protected void beforeRemove(){
    parent.getChildren().remove(this);
}
```

Comment: If you want to remain JPA-complaint, then you are not allowed to access/change any of the relationships. All you are allowed is to change own properties, like Strings, primitives... but no relationships.