# orphanRemoval doesn't work in JPA(Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

can anyone tell me why when I remove an entity object from a collection hibernate does not perform a DELETE operation even though I specified the orphanRemoval = true option?

I am using Spring boot with JPA/Hibernate, idk how it can can help, but I use PostgreSQL

do not beat for the quality of the code, this is just for example)

So here is code where I remove entity object from collection:

```
Content content = contentRepository.findById(1L).get();
ContentRating rating = content.getRatings().get(0);

content.getRatings().remove(rating);
rating.setContent(null);
```

Here is code of Content entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Content {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "content",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ContentRating> ratings = new ArrayList<>();

    // hashCode and equals implementations omitted
}
```

Here is code of ContentRating entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content_rating")
@Data
public class ContentRating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Content content;
    
    // hashCode and equals implementations omitted
}
```

Here is executed SQL queries:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.id 
    from
        content c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        r1_0.content_id,
        r1_0.id 
    from
        content_rating r1_0 
    where
        r1_0.content_id=?
```

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Share you pom.xml as well. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370940/orphanremoval-not-working-properly-in-hibernate-element-inserted-and-removed-f

Comment: My pom.xml is generated my Spring initializer, so I don't think it can help. Nope, that question is different(((

Comment: Still please share it. Need to see your dependencies.

Comment: @rahulP I've added pom.xml, if you need full pom.xml let me know

Comment: Need the version of these dependencies.

Comment: @rahulP
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

Comment: have you marked the method as @Transactional where you are doing the operation? If not, please mark it as transactional and try again.

Comment: @rahulP 
I've marked and it works, thank you sooo much for your time and explanations)

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone tell me why when I remove an entity object from a collection hibernate does not perform a DELETE operation even though I specified the orphanRemoval = true option?

Because that's not what `orphanRemoval` does.  Orphan removal is analogous to cascading deletes at the SQL level. It means that if the entity on the side of the relationship annotated with `orphanRemoval = true` is removed, then the entities orphaned by that removal -- the related ones on the other side of the relationship -- will automatically be removed too.

Just severing the relationship does not trigger orphan removal, and you can't actually sever the relationship from the non-owning side anyway.  (At least, not by manipulating the relationship field on that end.)

If you want to delete an entity that is on the "many" side of a many-to-one relationship then just do that.  If you want to update the entity on the "one" side without refreshing it from the DB then do that, too.